# Configuring calculated field with column type person in SharePoint Online

Tags: list, online, person, concatenate

I need to concatenate two columns in SharePoint, and one of them is type person. I saw that is possible to create a workflow (question 218041), but I can't use SharePoint Designer in this site. There is another way, using SharePoint Online?

Comment: Perhaps powershell could do that too

Answer (score 0):

Only below column types are supported in Calculated column according to Microsoft's [article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632):

## Supported

- Single line of text
- Number
- Date and Time

## Unsupported

- Multiple lines of text
- Currency
- Person or Group
- Calculated
- Hyperlink or Picture
- Custom Columns
- Yes/No
- Choice
- Lookup

So out of the box it's not possible. You may need to to look for the customization using Powershell or jQuery based solutions.